# C++ by example book

Tags: c++

I was programming in c++ at university but have been programming in java for most of my professional life(about 5 years) but I now need to recapture those c++ skills. I have tried a couple of books but they are too basic. Is there some kind of example book on c++ that I can use to revisit c++ in a project style format?

Comment: You might want to look at the [C++ book list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Under the circumstances, I'd consider *Accelerated C++*.

Comment: I think the comments and reviews on this book shows its the best for my situation so will go for that one. Thanks all for the help http://www.amazon.com/Professional-C-Wrox-Guides/dp/0470932449/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top

Answer (score 4):

When I was in a similar situation I read Scott Meyers' books. They both helped me to refresh C++, as well as widen my knowledge. Start with Effective C++ which contains a number of basic dos and don'ts with C++ to avoid common pitfalls.

http://aristeia.com/books.html

Comment: Thanks, but those books are very dry. I want something that takes me through a full application instead. Then I can come back to these ones you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Deitel's C++ for Programmers. I think it's a good one.

Answer (score 0):

There are many good books available for c++, but if you are really looking to refresh C++ then I would recommend c++ How to Program by H. M. Deitel -  Deitel & Associates. It has very good case studies n its fun to learn.

Comment: I tried the deitel book and quickly got bored. I don't want to learn Strings. I want to be working on something constructive

Comment: see this thread- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74405/what-is-the-best-c-book-for-an-intermediate-to-expert-developer

Answer (score -1):

I would like to recommend you the book:

«C++ Primer (5th Edition)», Stanley B. Lippman, Josée Lajoie, Barbara E. Moo ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714113)).

Comment: Highly disagree on this book in terms of "by example" - this is really just a great reference book, very thorough and well written introduction to the language. It would be a great book to have alongside an example book

Comment: @Keith, the book contains **many examples** have been revised to use the language features and demonstrate how to make the best use of them. But your mileage may vary.